# Limitations of Web App for Containers in Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service

We are planning to develop a new web application in Java or .NET. The application should be containerized using docker in Azure cloud platform and it should be scalable (user base at pick is about 80-90). Since, there is no need to develop a Microservice based application we have have planned to develop REST services in back end and Angular JS in front end as the application architecture.The Service back end will be deployed in web server and will run in one container and the Angular JS front end in another.

In this context will  Web App for container in Azure App service would be the right choice?

What are the limitations of Web App for containers?

Is there any limitations with Web App for containers in Azure App service if the application is developed using Java Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a good choice to develop a web application in Java or .NET and containerized it for deployment easier.

The limitation, please refer to the section [`App Service limits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits) of the offical document [`Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits).

And there is not any limits for using Java Spring Boot with WebApp for container on Linux. it's also same as do developing on Docker.

Additionally, just considered for developing REST service in back, I recommended you may use [Azure Functions in Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven) that I think easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run just Spring Boot, you can also use the "Java SE" offering which is available for Windows or Linux in App Service. In this case you just deploy your code and you don't need to worry about managing containers, like updating the JRE version, etc.

However, if you are interested in deploying a containerized app, you can use Windows Containers or Linux Containers in Azure App Service.